# Parse input text that is located using left padding spaces

Tags: parsing, awk

I have the following text structure. The values below `JTT  JNX  JNA  JNO` belong to previous line.

```
9   8    11  56507785                                     93
         JTT  JNX  JNA  JNO
          76        98

9   8    60  3269557                                      58
9   8    53  7269558                                     150
         JTT  JNX  JNA  JNO
         132   71       45-7705678

9   8    62  439559                                       82
```

I'd like to parse it in order to print the corresponding values in a single line like below:

```
H1    H2    H3    H4           H5    JTT  JNX  JNA  JNO
9     8     11    56507785     93     76        98
9     8     60    3269557      58    
9     8     53    7269558     150    132   71       45-7705678
9     8     62    439559       82
```

My issue is when I use awk with FS = space (default FS) then it takes JTT as first field and JTT has 9 spaces before, so I think should be use some technique that counts how may spaces are from left until `JTT  JNX  JNA  JNO` and count number of spaces from beginning until the values below `JTT  JNX  JNA  JNO` in order to positionate correctly each value. I mean, 76 and 132 below JTT header, 971 below JNX, 98 below JNA and 45-7705678 below JNO.

How can this be done in awk?

```
$ awk --version
GNU Awk 5.0.0, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, GNU MP 6.1.2)
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2019 Free Software Foundation.

$ uname -srv
CYGWIN_NT-6.1 3.0.7(0.338/5/3) 2019-04-30 18:08
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: update your Q with the output of `awk --version` and `uname -srv` . Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Hi. Updated with awk version and system.

Comment: Do you have to use awk?

Comment: @Shawn Well not needed. In Python or Ruby I have the option to run it. Or any other tool that can be installed on Cygwin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU awk (which you have) for FIELDWIDTHS:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    OFS = ","
    print "H1", "H2", "H3", "H4", "H5", "JTT", "JNX", "JNA", "JNO"
}
!NF || ($1 == "JTT") { next }
!/^ / {
    if (NR>1) {
        print rec
    }
    FS = " "
    $0 = $0
    $1 = $1
    rec = $0
}
/^ / {
    FIELDWIDTHS = "12 5 5 *"
    $0 = $0
    $1 = $1
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        gsub(/^\s+|\s+$/,"",$i)
    }
    rec = rec OFS $0
}
END {
    print rec
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
H1,H2,H3,H4,H5,JTT,JNX,JNA,JNO
9,8,11,56507785,93,76,,98
9,8,60,3269557,58
9,8,53,7269558,150,132,71,,45-7705678
9,8,62,439559,82

$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -s, -t
H1  H2  H3  H4        H5   JTT  JNX  JNA  JNO
9   8   11  56507785  93   76        98
9   8   60  3269557   58
9   8   53  7269558   150  132  71        45-7705678
9   8   62  439559    82
```

Replace `OFS=","` with `OFS="\t"` or otherwise massage to suit...

Comment: Hello Ed. Thanks so much. I only can say that works just perfect!  Very clean code. One question, what is the goal when you do `$0=$0` and `$1=$1`?

Comment: You're welcome. `$0=$0` tells awk to re-split the current record using the FIELDWIDTHS or FS value defined right above it instead of the FIELDWIDTHS/FS value that was populated when the current record was read. That's necessary because until that point the current record would have been split using the FIELDWIDTHS/FS setting from the **previous** line. `$1=$1` then tells awk to recombine the current fields using the value of OFS (so `x y` becomes `x,y`)

Comment: Thanks for your kind help and for the explanation.